# Restart the codeblock with a while-loop

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop, do-while, application-restart

**Problem**: I would like to restart my codeblock after the error message.

```cs
Console.Write("\tBitte geben Sie ihre erste Zahl ein: ");

if (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out zahl1))
    Console.WriteLine("\tUngültige Eingabe. Bitte geben Sie nur Zahlen an!");
```

Comment: Have you tried using a while loop?

Comment: Did you try to put it in a while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change your `if` into a `while`:

```
Console.Write("\tBitte geben Sie ihre erste Zahl ein: ");
while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out zahl1))
    Console.WriteLine("\tUngültige Eingabe. Bitte geben Sie nur Zahlen an!");
```

Comment: This would "work" but the user isn't prompted again to enter a number, so they won't know to type at the console again.

Comment: you are right, the message in the last line can be edited to ask again (please retry), unfortunately I don't speak German.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `do ... while` loop:

```
bool error;
do
{
    Console.Write("\tBitte geben Sie ihre erste Zahl ein: ");
    error = !double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out zahl1); 
    if (error)
        Console.WriteLine("\tUngültige Eingabe. Bitte geben Sie nur Zahlen an!");
} while(error);
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be very simple:

```
Console.Write("\tBitte geben Sie ihre erste Zahl ein: ");
while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out zahl1))
{
    Console.WriteLine("\tUngültige Eingabe. Bitte geben Sie nur Zahlen an!");

    Console.Write("\tBitte geben Sie ihre erste Zahl ein: ");
}
```

You need to make sure to prompt the user again, otherwise they will not know that they need to enter another number.

Comment: That isn't a good example. You are repeating code (the `Console.Write` calls)

Comment: @Adrian For the OP's purpose I think it is just fine to repeat it, since he is a beginner. It's a lot easier to understand what is happening, it can be refactored later to include just printing out the message in one place.